# Waiting for an iframe to be opened and scraped is too slow to scrape js

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, async-await, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape an old website built with tr, br and iframe. Everything was going good so far before I started to want to extract data from an iframe, see `iFrameScraping` setTimeout, but the clicking is too fast for me to be able to get the datas. Would anyone have an idea of how to click, wait for the content to show and be scraped, then continue?

```
  const newResult = await page.evaluate(async(resultLength) => {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

    for(i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
      const companyArray = elements[i].innerHTML.split('<br>');
      let companyStreet,
          companyPostalCode;

      // Get company name
      const memberNumber = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href').match(/[0-9]{1,5}/)[0];
      const companyName = await companyArray[0].replace(/<a[^>]*><span[^>]*><\/span>/, '').replace(/<\/a>/, '');
      const companyNumber = await companyArray[0].match(/[0-9]{6,8}/) ? companyArray[0].match(/[0-9]{6,8}/)[0] : '';

      // Get town name
      const companyTown = await companyArray[1].replace('"', '');

      // Get region name
      const companyRegion = await companyArray[2].replace(/<span[^>]*>Some text:<\/span>/, '');

      // Get phone number
      const telNumber = await elements[i].innerHTML.substring(elements[i].innerHTML.lastIndexOf('</span>')).replace('</span>', '').replace('<br>', '');


      const iFrameScraping = await setTimeout(async({elements, i}) => {
        elements[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
        const iFrameContent = await document.getElementById('some-id').contentWindow.document.getElementById('lblAdresse').innerHTML.split('<br>');
        companyStreet = iFrameContent[0].replace('"', '');
        companyPostalCode = iFrameContent[2].replace('"', '');
      }, 2000, {elements, i});

      console.log(companyStreet, companyPostalCode)
    };
  }, pageSearchResults.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issues after a while, so I'll share my solution.

I add to stop getting all the data with a loop from the evaluate because it's going to fast and creating a race condition. Instead I used a combination of page.$$ coupled with a for…of loop. Note that the forEach from es6 are causing race condition as well, since puppeteer does not wait for them to end to continue its execution.

Here is the example from my updated code:

```
 const companies = await page.$$('.repmbr_result_item');
  const companiesLinks = await page.$$('.repmbr_result_item a');

  for(company of companies) {
    const companyEl = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, company)
    const companyElArray = companyEl.split('<br>');
```